# Django: validate integrity of model taking into account the order of fields?

Tags: django, django-models

This is my `Symbol` model for cryptocurrency:

```
class Symbol(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name_quote = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('currency', 'name_quote', )
```

The problem is that there are two kind symbols, one for `BTC-ETH` and `ETH-BTC`. 
The first one means, currency is `BTC` and the name of coin is `ETH`. Second one, vice versa.

In this case, `django` recognizes both coins as the same one(because `unique_together` doesn't consider the order of field) so it occurs the `IntegrityError`.

How can I implement this taking into account the order of fields?

Answer (score 2):

`unique_together` means that two instances of `Symbol`cannot have the same `currency` *and* `name_quote`. The order does not matter.

See [the documentation for `unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for more info.